# How to retrieve Datatables filters using an external AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I need to call the `AJAX` function of my `DataTables` by pressing a button, so what I did is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

        <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <button>Fetch Data</button>
            <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var table;

function getDT() {
  $.ajax({
    Type: 'GET',
    url: '/ajax/objects.txt',
  }).done(function (result) {
    console.log(typeof result);
    result = JSON.parse(result);
    table.clear();
    table.rows.add(result.data).draw();
  });

}



$(document).ready(function() {
  table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]

  });
    
  table.row.add({
    name: 'aaa',
    position: 'temp',
    office: 'temp',
    extn: 'temp',
    start_date: 'temp',
    salary: 'temp',
  }).draw();
  
  $('button').on('click', function () {
    getDT();
  });
  

  
} );
```

Everything works well but I have a question: how can I retrieve the `DataTables` columns filter?

Infact, using an external `AJAX` call I need to pass manually all the parameters that I have to send to the `API` method, but how can I also pass: `order, search, start` that are usually sended automatically when I use the `ajax` property in `DataTables` like:

```
ajax: {
    url: '/ajax/objects.txt',
    method: 'GET'
},
```

I need to send all of this stuff in my custom `AJAX` call:

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. Why can't you use the ajax: option from DataTables?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Because I first need to select some filters in an options panel, then the user can apply those filters by pressing a button and get the data which populate the `DataTables`

Comment: You can add additional filters to the ajax: call as well. this might be easier as the other way around. But you can of course get the order by myDataTableVar.order() also

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff but there is an option to start the `DataTables` AJAX call only when the user press a button?

Comment: Ok, so you want the table to be empty until someone pushes a button?

Comment: "_how can I also pass: order, search, start that are usually sended automatically_" - those are only sent automatically when you are using `serverSide: true` - and in your sample code in the question, you are not using that. And anyway, that data does not come from filters in a custom options panel. It comes from the core table itself. I do find the scenario you are describing to be a bit confusing.

Comment: Having said that, there is `deferLoading` (for server-side processing) and there is `ajax.reload()` for re-playing the DataTable's ajax call (e.g. when a button is clicked). Using `reload()` you can send the latest settings from a custom panel to the server with each click.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understand what you need. This should be pretty easy using the ajax: option from DataTables. Just give a function with the data which is settings up some additional attributes like

```
const myTable = contentDiv.DataTable(
        {
            bProcessing : true,
            bServerSide : true,
            ajax :
            {
                dataType : "json",
                url : your url,
                type : "POST",
                data : function (d)
                {
                    d.data = getDataTableData();
                }
            },
            .....
```

then define this callback function like

```
function getDataTableData()
{
    return {
        showData : use a variable here which triggers your backend to give an empty list or even not,
        ... all your additional needed attributes...
        
    };
}
```

Now your backend can send an empty table if "showData" is not set and when a button is pressed, you changed the "showData" to true or 1 and call

```
myTable.ajax.reload();
```